# Range of a realistic on-planet-earth human Interaural Time Difference (ITD)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

What is the minimum and maximum of a realistic on-planet-earth human Interaural Time Difference (ITD)?

Please consider sound frequency and gas/liquid compositions which may influence the speed of sound, as well as as an estimation of the distances between ears; and/or other variables you may think of.

***Bonus question:*** how would the realistic ITD range vary when moving into outer space?

*Note:* I know this question requires both physics as well as some notion of biology (the spacing between ears). I deemed "Physics" to be more dominant in this question though (even though it may account for less variability in the range), hence appearing on this Stack Exchange sub-site.

Comment: The minimum is trivial. Think about it. And the maximum is also easy, though it does require two inputs, one about people and one about sound.

Comment: @dmckee "Small" as the range may be, I am curious to compare it to the factual human thresh-hold, as well as to compare it with that of e.g. sea animals; but that's more of a biological interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time difference is of course the path difference divided by the speed of sound.

Now you can start with " a human head is a sphere of radius $r$ ", and then you get a path difference $d$ (with one ear facing towards the source, and the other away) of $$d = r + \frac{\pi r}{2}$$

The velocity of sound is given by the molecular mass $M$, and the adiabatic constant $\gamma$ - both of which are a function of the kind of gas - as well as the temperature $T$:

$$c = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma R T}{M}}$$

Obviously, when you face the source "head-on" the path difference is zero.

You can extend this analysis to "going away from the planet": first, the composition of gas will change a little, and the temperature will change a lot. Finally, there will be no "speed of sound" as there will not be sufficient molecules per unit volume to give meaning to "sound".

Putting in some numbers, if $r=12~\rm{cm}$ and $c = 340~\rm{m/s}$, the maximum time difference is roughly 0.9 ms.